# How to prevent hiding Drupal 8 provided modal pop on escape key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8 provided modal pop but due to it's default behaviour it's hiding on pressing escape key but I want to prevent this default behaviour and I tried using jquery but it didn't work for me? May I know what else can be done to stop hiding it on escape key?

Used Jquery to prevent hiding but didn't work

```
$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { 
        $('.pop-up-class').show(); //Since I don't want to hide it
    }
});
```

I expect this not to be hidden on escape key using jquery but it's not able to overwrite the default behaviour of modal

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Drupal to experiment with, but this *might* help:

```
$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { 
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

A better version of this code would check the event target, and only `stopPropagation` if the target is the popup, or an element inside the popup.